# Can I use "is" twice in the question starting with "Is"?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, repetition, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I want to ask the below question:

> Is "West Indies" is not a country?

Here, can I use "is" twice? Or the second "is" not required and can I simply ask:

> Is "West Indies" not a country?

Comment: No you can't. Not unless you expand your question to *Is **it true [that]** "West Indies" is not a country?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @DJ McMayhem: If I thought that was an adequate answer, I'd have closevoted for lack of prior research. I'm waiting to see if anyone can explain *why* OP might be tempted to repeat the verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT use is two times!!

You just say:

**Is "West Indies" a country?**

Simple as that. Don't overuse the **is**!

Also you do not say:

I want to ask the below question:

You say:

I want to ask the **question below**:

or

I *would like* to ask the question below: